# Using replicate to create a simulation of my function

Tags: r, confidence-interval, replicate

Ive created this function to take samples from a random set of numbers that R generates and then compute the mean, standard deviation, and a confidence interval for those numbers. My goal is to try and replicate that in order to simulate a repeated sampling of confidence intervals. However, whenever I run my code with the replicate function, it returns a matrix of values from 1-10000, rather than returning my desired repeated sampling of confidence intervals. Here is my code that I have right now:

```
SampleCI <- function(n, mu, sigma){
  SRS <- rnorm(n = n, mean = mu, sd = sigma)
  SampleTest <- sample(SRS, size = 15)
  samplestatistics <- c(sum(!is.na(SampleTest)), mean(SampleTest), sd(SampleTest))
  names(samplestatistics) <- c("n", "sample mean", "StdDev")
  
  # 95% CI for mu
  L <- samplestatistics[2] - qt(.975, samplestatistics[1] - 1) * samplestatistics[3] / sqrt(samplestatistics[1])
  U <- samplestatistics[2] + qt(.975, samplestatistics[1] - 1) * samplestatistics[3] / sqrt(samplestatistics[1])
  CI <- c(L,U)
  
  list(samplestatistics = samplestatistics,
       CI = CI
       )
}
PossibleDataset <- SampleCI(100, 25, 3)
NSim = 10^4
testing <- replicate(NSim, PossibleDataset)
testing
```

Comment: Your function seems to be doing correct with `rnorm` and `sample`

Answer (score 1):

The `replicate` should be applied while applying the function and not on the output

```
outlst <- replicate(NSim, SampleCI(100, 25, 3), simplify = FALSE)
```

---

In the OP's code, the `SampleCI` is applied only once and then replicated the output `n` times

Comment: so what do I need to do so the SampleCI is replicated many times? I tried applying replicate while applying the function and not the output and still received a matrix of 1-10000

Comment: @BrysonBurr In your code, you are only replicating the same output N times rather than the SampleCI n times

Comment: So what do you suggest I do to replicate the SampleCI n times rather than the output?

Comment: @BrysonBurr because what you are doing is `v1 <- sample(1:5, 1); replicate(10, v1)` instead of `replicate(10, sample(1:5, 1))`

Comment: I understand that now of how what I have is incorrect, I just am not clear on what is needed to fix that. Do i add the replicate function inside of the function i created in order to accomplish that?

Comment: @BrysonBurr You meant the `matrix` output?  You need `simplify = FALSE` in `replicate` to return a `list`